# JMeter - SQL Server - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jmeter, pool, sqljdbc

JMeter 5.3.0

Trying to use the JDBC Connection Configuration.

Downloaded SQL Server JDBC libraries (sqljdbc8.2.2.0).

- put JAR files in {jmeter}\lib\
- put sqljdbc_auth.dll in {jmeter}\lib\
- also tried idea of using a library path in jmeter.bat as per https://performancebasics.wordpress.com/2016/01/25/setting-up-a-jdbc-sql-server-connection-in-jmeter/

[image]

Restarted JMeter

Attempted to run JDBC requests.

Still getting the error:

```
Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory 
(This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. 
ClientConnectionId:80cad180-02fe-43b3-841d-c1a1f8992607)
```

What else could I need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to choose only one .jar which matches your [JVM version](https://openjdk.java.net/install/):

   - `mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar` - for Java 8
   - `mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar` - for Java 11
   - `mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre13.jar` - for Java 13
2. You need to choose the right [architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) of the mssql-jdbc_auth library

   - `mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.2.x86.dll` - for 32-bit JVM
   - `mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.2.x64.dll` - for 64-bit JVM
3. You need to put this .dll file somewhere into `java.library.path`. The property value can be passed either via -D command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Djava.library.path=/path/to/folder/where/mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.2.xxx.dll
   ```

   or to make the change permanent you can add the relevant line to *system.properties* file:

   ```
   java.library.path=/path/to/folder/where/mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.2.xxx.dll
   ```

   More information:

   - [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
   - [Connecting with integrated authentication On Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15#Connectingintegrated)

Comment: Win 10 / Java 8, so chose mssql-jdbc-8.2.2..jre8.jar, and I used the -Djava.library.path option. verified that the argument was passed by looking in Task Manager. 

Restarted JMeter and ran the test plan. The error I get is the same as before.

Comment: I also verified using a JSR22 Sampler using `log.info(System.getProperty('java.library.path'))` that the path is `C:\<my path>\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.2.x64.dll`

Comment: As per the MIcrosoft article you cited, I tried `-Djava.library.path=<my path>\lib`, without the file-name at the end.  That didn't help either.

Comment: Ran with verbose settings.

This took me by surprise: 

`no mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.2.x86 in java.library.path`

Was not expecting x86 on a Windows 10 (x64) system.

I simply added this x86 DLL to the /lib folder and restarted.  This avoided the original error, but now Java runs out of memory in the JDBC test element and dumps heap, a different problem....

Comment: Finally got it to work.  As mentioned, I had to use the *x86* DLL even though I am running on Win10.   The out-of-memory error was because I was doing a `select *` on a big table.  I changed it to `select top 1 *` and it succeeded.